# Referencing the parts of a function - the "sub function" level, or "sub functional" level?

Tags: grammaticality

Here's the sentence I'm not sure how to write:

> I will show you how to write code of the highest standard, in the
> sub-function level.

What I mean by that is I will show how to write the parts of functions, not functions themselves.

Is it "sub-function", "sub-functional", something else?

Comment: It's probably better to use "function" to emphasise you're talking about functions as a software unit. [Functional](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/functional) has other meanings, including "performing or able to perform a function" i.e. working/operational. So sub-functional might be taken to mean "not working".

Comment: You can check for the relative idiomaticities of 'in the sub-function level' and 'at the sub-function level'; this might (or might not, if you consider the nuances different) sway your choice.

Comment: With the caveat that IT has its own language and this would probably be better answered on one of SE's computer forums - "I'll show you how to write elements of code to the highest standard,"

Comment: I suggest you be specific about the parts, for example maybe you want to teach people how to pass variables to a function?  "Sub-function" definitely does not work, in my opinion.